# How do I get cookie correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How do I get a cookie in the correct way, because the API which I want to use needs a cookie, so first I need to grab it using the post method for example

```cs
 _httpClient.SendAsync(request, token);
```

In the Authentication class I've got a static method where I am using httpClient:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient()
```

I tried to register it in Services like this:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient("Person", async (provider, client) =>
{
    var config = new PersonConfiguration(provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>());
    var cookie = await Authentication.GetCookie(config);

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.Link);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", cookie.Value);
})
```

but I am not entirely sure I should use async operation in lambda expresion. Any suggestions how I can solve that problem?

Comment: Please try to get cookie from HttpClient first.  Then confirm if this cookie is what you want ?

Comment: i found solution what i need DelegatingHandler and i added to AddHttpMessageHandler, this topic can be closed.